# Making a label expand in visual C#?

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

My application will expand to full screen.

But even if I have the label anchored, the label does not get bigger, and it stays in the top left of the screen?

Why is that?

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your anchor isn't correct. If you anchor on both the left and right sides, your label will stretch. Also, your label should have the `AutoSize` property set to `false`.

Comment: i have to wait 9 min...so...yeah

Comment: Hey, don't forget! It's been over 9 minutes. :)

Answer (score 3):

Set the `AutoSize` property to false. Also make sure that you set the anchor on **both sides** (`Left` and `Right` or `Top` and `Bottom`). You may also need to set the `TextAlign` property (because without that your text will not move and you probably will not be noticed of the resize).